Transformation of xhtml to docx using docx4j doesn't produce header/footer
I would like to produce docx from xhtml, including footer/header with page numbering. The input is:
String pXHTML += """
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
...
            @top-center {
                content: element(header)
            }
 
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer)
            }
        }
         
        div.header {
            display   : block;
            text-align: center;
            position  : running(header);
        }
  
        div.footer {
            display   : block;
            text-align: center;
            position  : running(footer);
        }
  
        .page-number::after {
            content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
        }
    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <div class="header">
        this is the header
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        this is the footer with page numbers <p class="page-number"></p>
    </div>
...
</body>
  
</html>       
"""

The code that process it is as follows:
String xhtmlText = addDoctype(pXHTML);
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackageXHTML =  WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackageXHTML);
wordMLPackageXHTML.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(xhtmlText, null));
Save saveToZip = new Save(wordMLPackageXHTML);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
saveToZip.save(byteArrayOutputStream);

The result page document has simply plain text
          this is the header     
          this is the footer with page numbers 

on the top of page.
How to convert it into proper header and footer, the latter with page numbering?

I have the same problem? solutions? help please
