Convertion from XHTML to DOCX using jodconverter 4.4.4
I want to convert properly formatted xhtml text to docx file. I tried it as follows:
File inputFile = new File("spreadsheet.xhtml");
File outputFile = new File("spreadsheet.docx");
JodConverter
         .convert(inputFile)
         .to(outputFile)
         .execute();

Content of the spreadsheet.xhtml is
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
...
            @top-center {
                content: element(header)
            }
 
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer)
            }
        }
         
        div.header {
            display   : block;
            text-align: center;
            position  : running(header);
        }
  
        div.footer {
            display   : block;
            text-align: center;
            position  : running(footer);
        }
  
        .page-number::after {
            content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
        }
    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <div class="header">
        this is the header
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        this is the footer with page numbers <p class="page-number"></p>
    </div>
...
</body>
  
</html>       

but I got -  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion.
How to do it properly?

It should be doable. I can convert from .xhtml to .docx at the command line (soffice --headless --convert-to "docx:MS Word 2007 XML" spreadsheet.xhtml) so it should be a matter of tweaking

Isn't this the same question you already asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78810521/transformation-of-xhtml-to-docx-using-docx4j-doesnt-produce-header-footer? Delete one of the two if they are the same. Don't duplicate questions just because you didn't got answers.

@aled wasn't the other one a Staging question?

@g00se it may have been in staging but it is published now.

If you think there is an actual duplicate then you can flag it in the usual way

@aled - it is not the same question - that uses docx4j, although the the aim - transformation xhtml -> docx is the same.
